# Embedding Web Snippets in Wiki Server and Security Settings

Tags: macos, security, osx-server, server.app

I want to edit the embed security settings in Mountain Lion Server's Wiki Service because with the default settings you can't embed anything on pages, which makes it a lot less useful. We're in a school environment where embedding flash apps, video etc. is the norm - and Wiki Server will normally strip out these tags from web snippets for security reasons.

[image: What happens when the embed tags aren't permitted]

I seems that to do this you change:

```
/Library/Server/Wiki/Config/whitelist.plist
```

but I'm not sure how to change it to allow all types of embeds. I'm aware of the security risks but I trust my users on this Server to embed what they need to embed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the [Lion Server Advanced Admin Guide](https://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/10.7/#apd59153f0a-7ed3-4c64-9c74-3a1fff831475) which mentioned changing the key  `FiltersEnabled` to `False` `/etc/collabd/collabd.plist`. 
Once I figured that this plist has been moved to /Library/Server/Wiki/Config in Mountain Lion Server from /etc/collabd/ in Lion Server I changed the preference - and we can embed to our hearts' content.