# OS X Server: Wiki embed youtube video on page

Tags: macos, osx-server, server.app

On OS X server using the wiki feature, I want to embed a youtube.com video onto a page. I thought the process would be to switch to HTML coding when making the Wiki Entry and cut and paste the HTML embedded like tag of youtube video into the post along with all the other content.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mylinkaddress" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When I save the page, it doesnt show up.... which makes sense since when I go back to edit the page and view the HTML, the  tag is no longer there. It seems like OS X server is rejecting the tag as invalid when saving the page.

How can I get OS X server to support embedding video into pages?

This occurs on the blog and wiki.

Update:
 this is the [Wiki Server](http://www.apple.com/osx/server/features/#wiki)

Answer (score 1):

I had [the same problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/84216/1818).

On the Server load terminal.app in your Utilities folder, and type in:

On Mountain Lion:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Server/Wiki/Config/collabd.plist FiltersEnabled false
```

On Lion:

```
sudo defaults write /etc/collabd/collabd.plist FiltersEnabled false
```

You may need to turn the Wiki Service off and on afterward for the settings to take affect. You can do this by typing:

```
sudo serveradmin stop wiki
```

then

```
sudo serveradmin start wiki
```

in the Terminal.

Comment: Neither of those paths exist on Mountain Lion
Looks like the path is /Library/Application Support/Apple/WikiServer but that didn't work either with this fix: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3147233?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: What version are you using? (e.g. 10.8.3)

Answer (score 0):

After trying this [solution](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3147233?start=0&tstart=0) and editing the following file

```
/Library/Application Support/Apple/WikiServer/whitelist.plist
```

I then realized that I needed to add the  tag from this [article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4600864?start=0&tstart=0)... duh

What I added was this the following XML to it:

```
        <key>iframe</key>
        <array>
            <string>frameborder</string>
            <string>title</string>
            <string>width</string>
            <string>height</string>
            <string>src</string>
            <string>allowfullscreen</string>
        </array>
```

The wiki server then needs to be cycled

```
sudo serveradmin stop teams
sudo serveradmin start teams
```

Here is the full [plist configuration](https://gist.github.com/cdesch/5337121)